# I am trying to display an error message if checkbox is not checked upon submit

Tags: reactjs

new to react- I need to validate a checkbox in react js

I have created a form with a checkbox that needs to be validated and ensure it is clicked when submitted. If not clicked display an error message.  I do not want an alert but a message displayed on the screen

```
const handleCheckBoxCheck = () => {
  const checkbox = userDetails.checkbox;
  if (checkbox === false) {
    alert('please confirm T&Cs');
  }
};

<div className={styles.checkbox}>
  <input
    type='checkbox'
    id={styles.checkbox}
    onChange={() => handleInput('checkbox', !userDetails.checkbox)}
    required='required'
  />
  <a>
    Terms and Conditions
    <span className={styles.required}>*</span>
  </a>
  {/* error message */}
</div>
```